# How to redirect to page after done working in webview?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-webview

I am working with another party system. When I sent request they provide me a URL. Which I load in webview. There is no way to acces that webview. I want to go automatically to another screen after done working in webview. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to load the WebView and then come back to the app again, after performing some actions.

There is a way to exchange the data between your app and WebView. Please check [this](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/25/send-receive-data-between-react-native-and-webview.html) article.

You can also use WebView's [onNavigationStateChange](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#onnavigationstatechange) prop to achieve your goal, if finishing the work is signalised by the URL change.

```
<WebView 
  onNavigationStateChange={this.yourAction}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but none of the solution is working for me

Comment: Please update your example and add some code snippets or please tell more about the use case